# Xcode build server showing blank web interface after OS X Server update

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

So after updating to OS X Server 3.1 (Build 13S4138) our Xcode Build web interface just returns a blank page. I'm sure everything is set up correctly because the source of the blank page shows a lot of metadata, so our dns routing is correct.

Can anyone make sense of this, or has experienced this problem and managed to resolve it?

Here is the source of the empty page I see where the xcode build web interface once was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="x-apple-config-DisableAllActivityView" content="false"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-config-DisableAllPeopleView" content="false"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-config-DisableAllProjectsView" content="false"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-config-MaxAttachmentFileSize" content="524288000"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-config-RecordSearchStats" content="false"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-route" content="/app-context/xcode/?.*"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-service-gitweb-enabled" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-service-webauth-enabled" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-service-xcode-enabled" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-sessionID" content="96b228e9-0541-4577-a3f1-62c927871fca"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-blogGUID" content="bd0df023-315e-4cea-bdbc-f333560a945b"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-can-create-bots" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-can-create-projects" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-externalID" content="7FAEA168-A97E-4CA0-84A6-43374FEA6016"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-guid" content="07d15a1c-c07f-44a9-adc5-936d0cd5e966"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-is-admin" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-isBlogEnabled" content="false"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-logged-in" content="true"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-longName" content="Admin"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-shortName" content="administrator"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-user-tinyID" content="S203R9"/>
    <meta name="x-apple-username" content="administrator"/>

    <link href="/__xcsweb/xcswebbase/stylesheets/compressed.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/__xcsweb/xcswebxcode/stylesheets/compressed.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/__xcsweb/xcswebbase/locales/en.lproj/strings.js" defer type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/__xcsweb/xcswebxcode/locales/en.lproj/strings.js" defer type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/__xcsweb/xcswebbase/javascripts/sprockets.js" defer type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/__xcsweb/xcswebxcode/javascripts/sprockets.js" defer type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body lang="en"></body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue - a slightly less drastic fix was as follows:

1. Quit the Server app
2. Drag the Server app to the trashcan (this disables all running services, you'll see a dialog box to that effect) - but don't empty the trash
3. Go to /Library/Server and make a copy of the Xcode directory for backup purposes.
4. Delete the /Library/Server/Xcode directory
5. Drag the Server app back from the trashcan and back to the Applications directory
6. Run the Server app again and follow the prompts

This should keep any server configurations apart from Xcode intact and give you a brand new (and more importantly - a functioning) Xcode server.  If you had code repositories on your Xcode server and want these back, you can recreate them in Server with the same names, and then replace the empty repositories created in /Library/Server/Xcode/Repositories/git/ with the original contents from the backup you made in step 3.

You'll have to recreate any Bots, and set up 3rd party repositories, certificates, and teams again, but this is less hassle than a complete OS reinstall.

Comment: I didn't even have to recreate any bots, etc (With server 3.2.2). This was a nicer solution that I was expecting :)

Comment: Even works with 4.1+. Just remove /Library/Developer/XcodeServer

Answer (score 1):

The short of it is... The fix was to uninstall the 'Server' App, then reinstall OS X on the server before it would start working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Internet (not local network) to access website, please make sure that in your router configuration that you have **443** port open

Answer (score 0):

My problem started when I upgraded to Xcode 7.1 on the server machine. Installing the [latest version of Xcode Server](https://developer.apple.com/osx/download/) (5.0.15) fixed it.